# Incorrect rendering of ASP.NET site in Chrome - fixed when clicked

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, rendering

I got this bug that began to occur in Chrome 17 and stayed with 18, when rendering an ASP.NET site.

What's going on is one of the pages renders incorrectly, BUT if I click on the webpage, or even on the scrollbar or on an html element in the chrome dev tools, then the components from the website snap back to their correct positions.  It is quite a complex website with lots of controls, and what happens visually is that some panels appear blank, some popups are shown, and some hidden controls are visible.

This isn't happening in any other browser or version, and never occurs the first time I enter the page.  It only occurs after a post-back has happened from within the same page.

I've noticed some CSS rules are set on the 'misbehaved' components, but are not being visually applied.  For example, I'm using chrome's console to inspect a custom dropdown menu which should be hidden.  When I retrieve the item, it has both the display:none and visibility:hidden properties, e.g.

```
<ul id="xx" style="position: absolute; left: 90px; top: 845px; display: none; visibility: hidden;> ... </ul>
```

However, when retrieving its display css property, it's 'block'.

```
$('#xx').css('display')
-block
```

Once I perform an action inside the webpage, the components snap to their correct layout, and the 'display' property is suddenly the correct 'none'.

I'm really out of ideas with this one.  There doesn't seem to be any code executed between the incorrect and correct rendering of the page.  My guess is maybe there are CSS conflicts between the asp code and the .css files, and maybe one is overwriting the other before it finished rendering.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe you didn't forget the closing double-quote for the `style` attribute in your real code, like you did above?

Comment: Sorry, that was a careless copy-paste.  The quotes are closed in the real code.

Comment: Yeah, there have been a few similar bugs lately, reported against WebKit...

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced this problem as well, in different versions of chrome.

This far. the only solution we've found is to simplify the html.

Looks lika a Chrome rendering bug to me.

I also don't think ASP got anything to do with it considering it doesn't run on the client side.